# Count the number of times True appers in last 5 rows of a column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate how many times does True appear in column in_trend in the last 5 rows
So considering `in_trend` column and last 5 rows

The below data should return `emacount`=3

```
    timestamp                     close    p_diff  ...  bb_side    emadiff  in_trend
191 2021-06-20 14:39:00+05:30  35205.83  0.348388  ...     True -17.065951     False
192 2021-06-20 14:42:00+05:30  35224.71  0.131215  ...     True -13.642527     False
193 2021-06-20 14:45:00+05:30  35189.40  0.044197  ...     True -15.706096     False
194 2021-06-20 14:48:00+05:30  35245.42  0.056861  ...     True  -8.875039     False
195 2021-06-20 14:51:00+05:30  35255.23  0.052819  ...     True  -7.095512     False
196 2021-06-20 14:54:00+05:30  35266.99  0.046941  ...     True  -5.299749     False
197 2021-06-20 14:57:00+05:30  35324.42  0.145489  ...     True   0.674513      True
198 2021-06-20 15:00:00+05:30  35370.05  0.124836  ...     True   4.955988      True
199 2021-06-20 15:03:00+05:30  35353.62  0.177176  ...     True   2.919227      True
```

The below data should return `emacount`=4

```
 timestamp                     close    p_diff  ...  bb_side    emadiff  in_trend
190 2021-06-20 14:39:00+05:30  35205.83  0.348388  ...     True -17.065951     False
191 2021-06-20 14:42:00+05:30  35224.71  0.131215  ...     True -13.642527     False
192 2021-06-20 14:45:00+05:30  35189.40  0.044197  ...     True -15.706096     False
193 2021-06-20 14:48:00+05:30  35245.42  0.056861  ...     True  -8.875039     False
194 2021-06-20 14:51:00+05:30  35255.23  0.052819  ...     True  -7.095512     False
195 2021-06-20 14:54:00+05:30  35266.99  0.046941  ...     True  -5.299749     False
196 2021-06-20 14:57:00+05:30  35324.42  0.145489  ...     True   0.674513      True
197 2021-06-20 15:00:00+05:30  35370.05  0.124836  ...     True   4.955988      True
198 2021-06-20 15:03:00+05:30  35353.62  0.177176  ...     True   2.919227      True
199 2021-06-20 15:06:00+05:30  35333.78  0.104324  ...     True   0.751682      True
```

The below should return `emacount` =3

```
timestamp                     close    p_diff  ...  bb_side    emadiff  in_trend
190 2021-06-20 14:45:00+05:30  35189.40  0.044197  ...     True -15.706096     False
191 2021-06-20 14:48:00+05:30  35245.42  0.056861  ...     True  -8.875039     False
192 2021-06-20 14:51:00+05:30  35255.23  0.052819  ...     True  -7.095512     False
193 2021-06-20 14:54:00+05:30  35266.99  0.046941  ...     True  -5.299749     False
194 2021-06-20 14:57:00+05:30  35324.42  0.145489  ...     True   0.674513      True
195 2021-06-20 15:00:00+05:30  35370.05  0.124836  ...     True   4.955988      True
196 2021-06-20 15:03:00+05:30  35353.62  0.177176  ...     True   2.919227      True
197 2021-06-20 15:06:00+05:30  35333.78  0.104324  ...     True   0.751682      True
198 2021-06-20 15:09:00+05:30  35295.48  0.076508  ...     True  -2.967526     False
199 2021-06-20 15:12:00+05:30  35245.00  0.091845  ...     True  -7.492524     False
```

and so on basically the value will vary between 0 (if none in the last 5 are true) and 5(if all in the last five are true) based on in_trend column data

I thought of this code But it is correct only some times. Is there any easy and more effective way to achieve this

```
        emaccount=0
        for now in range(len(df.index) - 5, len(df.index)):
            if df['in_trend'][now]:
                emacount = emacount + 1
            else:
                emacount = emacount -1
```

Comment: I don't think you need the else condition in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html#pandas-dataframe-tail) 5 then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas-series-sum) `in_trend`:

```
emacount = df.tail(5)['in_trend'].sum()
```

Sample Frame:
`df`:

```
   in_trend
0      True
1     False
2     False
3      True
4      True
5      True
6     False
7      True
8     False
```

`df.tail(5)`:

```
   in_trend
4      True
5      True
6     False
7      True
8     False
```

`emacount`:

```
3
```